# Facebook messenger 196.0.0.29.99 keeps crashing

Tags: facebook-messenger

I am using LG G6 Stock Oreo 8.0 and everything is working fine except Facebook messenger, it keeps crashing after a while without returning an error. I then took log from my phone and attached here. Please if anyone could read it and help me out to fix the issue. Facebook version below 189 and lite version are working fine. Only this version is crashing.

Logcat: http://saadtariq.net/logcat.txt

Comment: The link you provided is broken.

Comment: Have you tried cleaning its cache? Uninstall then reinstall?

Comment: @parthu_panther please check the link now, just updated.

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio yes did everything, completely uninstall both messenger and facebook app, removed all traces etc still no use :(

Comment: I'm facing the same problem after updating it. I installed Facebook lite messenger for now

Comment: V187 also worked fine for me too. I installed that downgraded version for now using apkmirror

Comment: so strange. they have changed something